# How to compute for a specific area height using AngularJS/CSS (No jQuery)

Tags: css

AngularJS newbie here. Is there a way to compute for a specific area in the page using AngularJS and/or CSS?

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is filling up the blank space below the last item of the navigation menu. I don't want for it to overlap with the footer. Reason why I want to compute for it is for it to adjust whenever user zooms out of the page.

[image: Screen goal]

This was my earlier attempt:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="blankSpace">
```

**CSS**

```
 div.blankSpace {
     background-color: #35444f;
     background-repeat: repeat-y;
 }
```

... but this didn't work.

Any tips will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is plain CSS problem. Google "css sidebar height 100 percent" for some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using css3 or Angular directive.

//  CSS

// Assume your header and footer height are 100px respectively.

```
#sidebar {
height: -moz-calc(100% - (100px + 100px));
height: -webkit-calc(100% - (100px + 100px));
height: calc(100% - (100px + 100px));
```

}

```
yourAppName.directive('sidebar', ['$document', '$window', function ($document, $window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                var headerHeight = 100px;
                var footerHeight = 100px;

                var d = $document.height() - headerHeight - footerHeight;


                scope.changeHeight = function() {
                    element.css('min-height', d );
                    console.log(d);
                };
                scope.changeHeight();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

// HTML Code Or Directive

```
<aside sidebar></aside>
```